# Aligning arrows

Tags: arrows

I have a question. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  $\left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 
  \textrm{math stuff} & \\
  \textrm{in}&\\
  \textrm{here} &
  \end{array}\right\}\leftrightarrow 
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl}  
  \textrm{and} & \\
  \textrm{some stuff in here} &\\
  \end{array}\right\}.$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  $\left\{\begin{array}{cl}  %
  \textrm{other stuff} & \\
  \textrm{in} &\\
  \textrm{right here} &
  \end{array}\right\}\leftrightarrow 
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
  \textrm{and} & \\
  \textrm{finally} &\\
  \textrm{here}\\
  \end{array}\right\}.$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like to have is, that the arrows are aligned. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You do not need to use `\begin{center}...`. If you put your math code in some equation environment, it will get centered automatically in a `report`. The `$ $` is for inline math. The package should load all you need for typesetting math. Therefore I would remove the 4 ams packages (if it yields errors for you, try which one is actually needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just put it in an align environment:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl} 
  \textrm{math stuff} & \\
  \textrm{in}&\\
  \textrm{here} &
  \end{array}\right\}&\leftrightarrow 
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl}  
  \textrm{and} & \\
  \textrm{some stuff in here} &\\
  \end{array}\right\}.\\
      \left\{\begin{array}{cl}  %
  \textrm{other stuff} & \\
  \textrm{in} &\\
  \textrm{right here} &
  \end{array}\right\}&\leftrightarrow 
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
  \textrm{and} & \\
  \textrm{finally} &\\
  \textrm{here}\\
  \end{array}\right\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, exactly what I wanted.